# Restrict the unauthorized users from the magento site

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

Customer can register the details as usual in magento site.  Admin can view the registered customer details via admin dashboard. Once admin can approve the details valid customers can able to login into the site invalid customers in the sense they need to be resticted from the usage of the site.

This is the concept but I don't know how to do.. Please share your valuable comments.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to use **Netzarbeiter_CustomerActivation** [extension](https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation). It's free

Comment: Please don't post single link answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will just have to install the extension from [here](https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation) and install it to your magento store, after active that extension any user can't login until admin approve their account.